# I Am trying to fill a form using webriver, it works fine with the firefox but in chrome all the text fields becomes blank after clicking on submit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I Am trying to fill a form using webriver, it works fine with the firefox but in chrome all the text fields becomes blank after clicking on submit

the execution stops after the field values become blank

Comment: i have tried the code with the implicit wait after every field value, but no improvement

Comment: Please show the code that you're using and the relevant html snippet, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue but with a TinyMC Body whereby it works fine with firefox but doesn't with chrome.

Was able to resolve this by executing i.e editing the field and saving using some javaScript by checking if the browser is not Firefox.

here's a snippet to give you an idea, hope this helps

```
        Capabilities browser = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();

        if (browser.getBrowserName().equals("chrome")) {

             try {
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                        "JavascriptCode", element);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO
        }
```

Comment: No, this code is not working for me...

same problem exists.. even i have increased the wait for to locate elements properly. but its not working even now.

please let me know if you have any other solution for this.

Comment: Do you have the javaScript snippet your executing ?

Comment: I suggested using JavaScript to fill the form if the browser is not Firefox.. You just need to get your elements right and do all the necessary actions can be via JQUery
Like $("#unit8").click() //Or however you want to treat the elements